# Linq: Get Items which intersect

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am new to this and I have a little trouble to do this:

I have a list of `timeitems`:

```
06:40 - 07:10
06:55 - 07:13
07:00 - 08:35
07:13 - 07:14
09:00 - 10:00
10:00 - 11:00
12:00 - 13:00
12:30 - 14:00
```

Now I want all items which intersects:

```
06:40 - 07:10
06:55 - 07:13
07:00 - 08:35
07:13 - 07:14

12:00 - 13:00
12:30 - 14:00


var intersects = timeitems
            .Where(a => timeitems
            .Any(b => Utilities.IsBetween(a.SpanRangeStartIndex, b.SpanRangeStartIndex, b.SpanRangeEndIndex)))
            .AsParallel()
            .ToList();
```

But I only get this and I don´t know why:

```
06:55 - 07:13
07:00 - 08:35
07:13 - 07:14

12:30 - 14:00
```

Thanks four your help (Remember, I am new to .net :-)

edit*

ok, a timeitem ist just a list of items with two properties:

Item1(SpanRangeStartIndex=06:40    SpanRangeEndIndex=07:10 )

Item2(SpanRangeStartIndex=06:55    SpanRangeEndIndex=07:13 )

...

Utilities.IsBetween checks if a value is between two other values  (if 3 is between 2 and 6 -> true)

```
    public static bool IsBetween(int value, int start, int end)
    {
        return (value > start) & (value <end);
    }
```

Sorry for my bad English and bad c#-skill... I am very new to this

thanks

Comment: What is `timeItems` and what is the code of `Utilities.IsBetween`?

Comment: You are overloading the term `intersect` a little. You want to know wich ranges in one list overlap with ranges in another list. First of all, is each list a set? Second, how do you define equality for a range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing this problem because you are only getting "items such that this item starts during another item", and not including "items such that another item starts during this item".

A simple fix would be

```
var intersects = timeitems
    .Where(a => timeitems.Any(b => 
        Utilities.IsBetween(a.SpanRangeStartIndex,
            b.SpanRangeStartIndex, b.SpanRangeEndIndex) ||
        Utilities.IsBetween(b.SpanRangeStartIndex,
            a.SpanRangeStartIndex, a.SpanRangeEndIndex)))
    .AsParallel()
    .ToList();
```

which makes your code symmetrical and would include the missing `06:40 - 07:10` and `12:00 - 13:00`.

However, this (as with your original) is very inefficient - O(n^2), when an O(n) algorithm should be possible.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `O(n!)`? That's significantly worse than `O(n^2)`... (I guess you mean `n + (n-1) + (n-2) ... ~= (n^2)/2`)

Comment: You're right, perhaps I'm getting the notation wrong, but I've prevented from having to use `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

I believe the problem that you're trying to solve is that you want to know which ranges in your set of ranges overlap any of the other ranges in the same set.

The problem seems to be that you test one end of the range for "between" but not the other.
(I wrote a sample program that does what yours does and added some comments and removed the 'SpanRange' and 'Index' from the property names as well as the `.AsParallel()` call - which might change the order of the data returned but still have the same overall content.)

```
var intersects = 
    data.Where(a => data
        .Any(b => 
            IsBetween(a.Start, b.Start, b.End) // <-- this is the test you did
            || IsBetween(a.End, b.Start, b.End) // <-- the missing other end
//          || IsBetween(b.Start, a.Start, a.End) // potentially necessary
//          || IsBetween(b.End, a.Start, a.End) // potentially necessary
        ));
```

I added the other two commented `IsBetween` calls since I think there are likely "completely contained" range tests that might fail to show when one range is completely contained within the other.

On a different note, I might try to change your thinking a little bit on how to test when ranges intersect by first thinking of the simpler case of how two ranges would NOT intersect.

Two ranges do not intersect when either:

1. `rangeA.End < rangeB.Start` which says: rangeA is entirely 'to the left of' rangeB
2. `rangeA.Start > rangeB.End` which says: rangeA is entirely 'to the right of' rangeB

`doNotIntersect = (rangeA.End < rangeB.Start) || (rangeA.Start > rangeB.End)`

Thus we can test whether ranges intersect by negating the above expression:
`isIntersecting = (rangeA.End >= rangeB.Start) && (rangeA.Start <= rangeB.End)`

However, I noted that your between test doesn't use ">=" or "<=" so a range that shares only an end with the other's start doesn't intersect. Because of this, the `09:00 - 10:00` range in the sample would not overlap with the `10:00 - 11:00` range in the sample. So, it's likely you would use `>` & `<` rather than the `>=` & `<=` operators.

I'd be happy to post the code and the results if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Think of when you are dealing with the time from `12:30` to `14:00`

The preceding element (from `12:00` to `13:00`) intersects with that window, but your query misses it because you are only checking to see if the *start* time is in the range when you have to check if the *end* time is in the range.

That said, you can change your query to this (removed the [`AsParallel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel.aspx) and `ToList` methods as they aren't integral to the solution):

```
var intersects = timeitems
    .Where(a => timeitems
        .Any(b => 
            // Check the start of the window...
            Utilities.IsBetween(a.SpanRangeStartIndex, 
                b.SpanRangeStartIndex, b.SpanRangeEndIndex) &&
            // *AND* the end of the window...
            Utilities.IsBetween(a.SpanRangeEndIndex, 
                b.SpanRangeStartIndex, b.SpanRangeEndIndex)));
```

Right now, you're iterating through the *entire* `timeItems` sequence for *every* item, even items that you know have already been matched and intersect (since you're not pairing them, you don't need to say item `a` overlaps with item `b`, you simply have to return that it overlaps).

With this in hand, you can reduce having to iterate through N^2 items by not using LINQ, but only if your collections are materialized and implement the [`IList<T>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx), which arrays and [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instances do).

You would look ahead, keeping track of what overlaps and was yielded, like so:

```
public IEnumerable<TimeItem> GetOverlappingItems(this IList<TimeItem> source)
{
    // Validate parameters.
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    // The indexes to ignore that have been yielded.
    var yielded = new HashSet<int>();

    // Iterate using indexer.
    for (int index = 0; index < source.Count; ++index)
    {
        // If the index is in the hash set then skip.
        if (yielded.Contains(index)) continue;

        // Did the look ahead yield anything?
        bool lookAheadYielded = false;

        // The item.
        TimeItem item = source[index];

        // Cycle through the rest of the indexes which are
        // not in the hashset.
        for (int lookAhead = index + 1; lookAhead < source.Count; ++lookAhead)
        {
            // If the item has been yielded, skip.
            if (yielded.Contains(lookAhead)) continue;

            // Get the other time item.
            TimeItem other = source[lookAhead];

            // Compare the two.  See if the start or the end
            // is between the look ahead.
            if (Utilities.IsBetween(item.SpanRangeStartIndex,
                    other.SpanRangeStartIndex, other.SpanRangeEndIndex) ||
                Utilities.IsBetween(item.SpanRangeEndIndex,
                    other.SpanRangeStartIndex, other.SpanRangeEndIndex))
            {
                // This is going to be yielded.
                lookAheadYielded = true;

                // Yield the item.
                yield return other;

                // Add the index to the hashset of what was yielded.
                yielded.Add(lookAhead);
            }
        }

        // Was a look ahead yielded?
        // No need to store the index, we're only moving
        // forward and this index doesn't matter anymore.
        if (lookAheadYielded) yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although your code is good, you examples aren't; OP isn't _expecting_ the `9:00-10:00` or `10:00-11:00` items to show up, and they're excluded because (I expect) `IsBetween` excludes the endpoints rather than because of the start/end check.

Comment: @Rawling Neither of us can tell because `IsBetween` isn't shown; if you take a SQL Server definition, it's inclusive, and it works.  But I've updated with an overlapping time range that is semantically the same but doesn't raise the question of whether or not `IsBetween` is inclusive or exclusive.

Comment: `IsBetween` isn't shown, but the expected results are shown and `09:00 - 10:00` and `10:00 - 11:00` aren't there. Whether or not you use that to infer the inclusiveness of `IsBetween`, I still wouldn't use those two results as an example of what _should_ be included.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ might not be a good idea here, as you're doing a LOT of double counting. If you can assume they're all sorted by the starting index (which you can just order it using LINQ if you can't make that guarantee) then it's a whole lot easier to keep a rolling window as you iterate over them:

```
timeitem workingRange = null, rangeStart = null;
bool matched = false;
foreach(timeitem t in timeitems) // timeitems.OrderBy(ti => ti.SpanRangeStartIndex) if unsorted
{
    if(workingRange is null)
    {
        rangeStart = t;
        workingRange = new timeitem { SpanRangeStartIndex = t.SpanRangeStartIndex, SpanRangeEndIndex = t.SpanRangeEndIndex };
        continue;
    }

    if(Utilities.IsBetween(t.SpanRangeStartIndex,
        workingRange.SpanRangeStartIndex, workingRange.SpanRangeEndIndex))
    {
        if(!matched)
        {
            matched = true;
            yield return rangeStart;
        }
        workingRange.SpanRangeEndIndex = Math.Max(workingRange.SpanRangeEndIndex, t.SpanRangeEndIndex);
        yield return t;
    }
    else
    {
        matched = false;
        rangeStart = t
        workingRange = new timeitem { SpanRangeStartIndex = t.SpanRangeStartIndex, SpanRangeEndIndex = t.SpanRangeEndIndex };
    }
}
```

A few notes. Keeping a reference to the original first item of the range, since I don't know whether it's a struct/class and it's better to yield the original items unless you're performing some sort of transformation. The working range can easily be modified to use `DateTime` (which might be easier to read/understand). We need to keep track of whether we've matched yet, because we still need to yield/return the original working item and ensure we don't yield it again (can't use ranges as a measure, as subsequent `timeitem`s could be entirely within the initial range). Finally, if the item we're checking is not within the range, we reset all our state variables and treat them as our beginning range.

This ensures you only ever have to traverse through the collection once, at the expense of sorting it beforehand (which, if you can ensure they get to this point sorted in the first place you eliminate that need anyway). Hope that helps, wish there was an easier way.